# What are the references or terms for the word sukkah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, sukkah, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, symbols-symbology

Which words or descriptions serve as references for the word sukkah? I will accept any and all sources that are accepted here at mi yodeya.

Answer (score 2):

Two that spring to mind are the following:

1. In [Gemara Succah 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.3a.6?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en) (amongst other places) there is a reference to Succah as being a **מטללתא** as in "אפומא דמטללתא" - *the entrance of the Succah*. See the [Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%98%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%90.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) below for the source of the word:

> מַטְלָלָא, מְטָלָא m. (טְלַל I) shelter, hut, booth. Targ. Ps. X, 9 (Ms. מְטַלְלָא).—Y. Succ. III, beg. 53ᶜ עביד ליה מטלא וכ׳ put up a festive booth for himself in the street.—Pl. (מְטַלַּיָּא) מְטָלַיָּא. Targ. O. Lev. XXIII, 42 (ed. Amst. מְטָלַיָּת, corr. acc.). Targ. II Sam. XI, 11; a. fr.

> מְטַלַלְתָּא, מְטַלְּתָא f. same. Targ. Is. I, 8. Targ. Jon. IV, 5. Targ. Y. Lev. XXIII, 42; a. e.—Constr. מְטַלַּת (מַטְלַת). Targ. O. ib. 43 מְטַלַּת (Ms. I מְטָלָיוּת, III מְטַלַּת pl.). Targ. Is. IV, 6.—Esp. festive booth, Succah. Succ. 3ᵃ אפומא דמטלל׳ Ms. M. (ed. מטולתא, מטלתא, v. Rabb. D. S. a. l. note) at the entrance of the Succah. Ib. 28ᵇ במ׳ in the Succah, בר ממ׳ without the Succah (in the house &c.). Y. M. Kat. III, 82ᵃ הוות מְטַלְּתֵיה וכ׳ if his (the mourner’s) Succah is small; a. fr.—[Treat. S’maḥ. ch. XI, end מטלתא דכרמא the watchman’s hut in the vineyard—a mistaken gloss to אודייני, which found its way into the text; v. M. Kat. 27ᵃ, a. אוּרְיָינִי.]—Pl. מְטַלָּתָא, מְטַלָּן. Targ. O. Lev. l. c., v. supra. Targ. Gen. XXXIII, 17 (Y. מַטְלָן).

2. The famous alternative reference is '**צִלָּא דִּמְהֵימְנוּתָא**' - lit. the shade of faith - see the [Zohar 3:103b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.103b.8?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

> תָּא חֲזֵי, בְּשַׁעֲתָא דְּבַר נָשׁ יָתִיב בְּמָדוֹרָא דָּא, צִלָּא דִּמְהֵימְנוּתָא, שְׁכִינְתָּא פַּרְסָא גַּדְפָהָא עָלֵיהּ מִלְּעֵילָּא, וְאַבְרָהָם וַחֲמִשָּׁה צַדִּיקַיָּיא אָחֳרָנִין שַׁוְיָין מָדוֹרֵיהוֹן עִמֵּיהּ.
>
> *Come and see, when one sits in this dwelling in the shade of faith, the Divine presence spreads Her wings over him from above, and Avraham and five other righteous ones after him (i.e. the Ushpizin) come to dwell with him.*

Comment: +1. So a synonym for a Sukkah (based on these references) are: "shelter" or "watchman's hut" or "shade of faith". These sounds great. On an unrelated note, but also in your reference, why does your quote say "Avraham and five other righteous ones" when I thought there were 7 Ushpizin?

Comment: Yes I noticed that as well(!) The Zohar only details six (Avraham + 5)  - anyone have an answer for that one?

Comment: ? https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.104a.2?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en\

Comment: @Dov Your answer specifically uses the term "the entrance of the Succah" and I was wondering if the word "tent" is also a synonym, in that when Abraham was sitting at "the entrance of the tent" (in Genesis 18), whether or not it was a Sukkah or a Tent (not that I know what the Torah definition of a Tent is).

Comment: I clearly didn't read that far @Dr.Shmuel lol

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I do not understand Hebrew very well. Did you just point out that there are 7 Ushpizin in the Zohar, too?

Comment: @Dov did the word "tent" ever serve as a reference or term for a sukkah?

Comment: Your translation, "אפומא דמטללתא", even according to Jastrow is incorrect. מטללתא is a verb, not a masculine noun. It should read, "If therefore it is covered...". Your quotations from Jastrow are mixing the verb which means, "to cover", with the masculine noun which has a meaning of shade or shadow.

Comment: The word, "sukkah" (סכה or סוכה) is from the root word, "s'kach" (סכך) like is stated in Jastrow. It means shade.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I am aware about the word succah stemming from sechach (in fact is brought by rashi in the final dibbur hamaskil on the mishna on Gemara Succah 2a). However, the OP asked for alternative references to Succah which I have supplied. I just checked in the Artscroll as well, and they also translate it as 'at the entrance of the Succah'

Comment: @Dov Whoever made the particular translation you mention would need to explain why they are treating a verb with one meaning as a noun that has a completely different meaning. But what is found in Jastrow as I commented is the traditional meaning. Perhaps they also misunderstood the grammar.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Jastrow quoted by Dov explicitly translates אפומא דמטללתא as ‘at the entrance of the Succah’

Comment: @JoelK You are looking at the incorrect root word. If you have the Jastrow in hardcover, try looking at the complete pages. This is part of the disadvantage of using the Sefaria version. It’s all disjointed and out of context.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Dov quoted a phrase from Sukkah 3a - אפומא דמטללתא. Jastrow, as quoted by Dov, quotes **the very same phrase from the very same place**, and translates it following Dov’s understanding: “ Succ. 3ᵃ אפומא דמטלל׳ Ms. M. (ed. מטולתא, מטלתא, v. Rabb. D. S. a. l. note) at the entrance of the Succah.” If you still wish to claim that Jastrow  would translate this phrase differently to how he himself translates it, the burden of proof is very much on you. I have the print edition of Jastrow; please provide a precise reference to where you believe he supports your understanding.

Comment: @JoelK In Jastrow, Vol.1, p.536, masc. noun טלי; p.537 verb root טלל listing I & III; and similarly preceding it on same page טלית. And the reference in Dov's answer is to Jastrow, Vol. 2, p.768 which references the masc. noun usage of מטלא, מטללא and also the fem. noun usage מטלתא, מטללתא which he indicates both derive from the verb root טלל cited above from p.537 meaning to cover, screen or shade (referencing the concept of s'kach). Jastrow seems to say the variant translation Dov is pointing to originates with Rabbinowicz in the 1870's, much later (see Vol. 1 p.XVIII).

Answer (score 0):

The word sukkah is a remez to the 3 ways one can build a kosher sukkah; the ס is the most mehudar way- 4 complete walls. The כ represents a sukkah of three walls. And the ה represents the bare minimum of 2 walls with a tefach of a third wall.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't remember where I heard this from.